# Find the distributions of two random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, negative-binomial

An SMS message is sent through a communication channel with multiple servers, starting from 0. In each second, the message can be transmitted to the next server with a probability P, or remain on the server and wait.

Let $Xi$ be the random variable which gives the number of seconds needed for the message to be received by the $i$-th server. Find the distributions of $x1$ and $x2$

I think this is poisson distribution but I've no idea where or how to start. Any help?

Comment: It's negative binomial distribution as you're waiting for the i-th success.

Comment: So what would the solution look like? I'm really struggling with these :/

Comment: For x1: x ~ NB(1, p) ?

Comment: Yes $X_1 \sim NB(1, p)$ which is also called geometric distribution and 
$X_2 \sim NB(2, p)$.

Note that this is "Type-I negative binomial" as it's counting numbers of trials rather than number of failures(which is Type-II negative binomial)

Comment: So this means I just have to replace the values in the formula and that's it?

Comment: Yup, thats it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$X_1$ = the number of seconds it takes to move from server 0 to 1.   As we are the counting Bernoulli trials until a success, this will have a **Geometric distribution**, $X_1\sim\mathcal{Geo}_1(p)$.

$$X_1\sim\mathcal{Geo}_1(p) \quad\iff\quad \mathsf P(X_1=x_1)= (1-p)^{x_1-1}p$$

---

$X_2-X_1$ = the number of seconds it takes to move from server 1 to 2.   This will also have a geometric distribution, iid to $X_1$.

Thus we have the **join pmf**: $\;P_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2)= \mathsf P(X_1{=}x_1, X_2{=}x_2)\\ \qquad = \mathsf P(X_1{=}x_1)\;\mathsf P(X_2{-}X_1{=}x_2{-}x_1) \\ \qquad \ddots \text{(can you complete?)}$

---

You can use this joint distribution to evaluate the marginal for $X_2$.

However we can *also* assert that $X_2$ will have a negative binomial distribution as it is the count of trials until the second success.  Thus to obtain $X_2=x_2$ we require 1 success and $x_2-2$ failures in some order, followed by a final success.

$$X_2\sim\mathcal{NB}(2, p) \quad\iff\quad \mathsf P(X_2{=}x_2) = \dbinom{n}{x_2-2}(1-p)^{x_2-2}p^2$$

Comment: I understand for X1, but not the second part :/

Comment: Why not?  The second verse is the same as the first.  Every second the server will be transmitted from the server that it is in onto the next with probability $p$.   Hence the time it takes to move to the next server will be : *Geometrically Distributed* : $$\;X_{n+1}{-}X_n \;\sim\;\mathcal{Geo}_1(p)\qquad\big [X_{n+1}{-}X_{n}\in\{1,2,\ldots\}\big]$$

Comment: I meant the second part, where you asked me to complete it (I haven't revised vectors yet)

Comment: There are no vectors involved.  It's a straight substitution of formula and simplification.

Comment: Back to reading theory I guess :)